# How do I make it so that the textures of my model show up when uploaded to sketchfab

Tags: texturing

So I made a model in blender and was uploading it to sketchfab when I noticed that the model seemed to lack some of the custom textures that I had used while modelling it. [image: The image in blender]

I exported it as an obj and attached the texture
[image: The nodes of the texture]

I then uploaded it to sketchfab and the model looks like this which is not what I need.
[image: Sketchfab output]

How do I export the textures so they show up properly?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Upto what I know, there's a CG Geek tutorial about exporting to sketchfab on YouTube... Though you can't get textures in an object file, only the gtlf format supports that.